# How to access the cardboard trigger on google Gvr( in code)? 1.6 version SDK

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

How to access the cardboard trigger on google Gvr( in code) ? In the earlier version it was GvrViewer.Instance.Triggered

Comment: I just use `Input.OnMouseButtonDown(0)` which perfectly works for touch devices as well, no problem in VR either

Comment: Ok. Thanks! I use it too Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) but i didn't test in VR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `Input.GetButtonDown("Fire 1")` and it works for me on the latest SDK version (1.6) and latest Unity version (5.6)

EDIT:
Use `Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")` if you follow the default naming conventions for input events supported by unity. Please note that there is no space character between "Fire" and "1".

Otherwise, you might the error - "ArgumentException: Input Button Fire 1 is not setup."

Comment: Fire 1 in Unity is actually MouseButton(0) (left click) and left Ctrl :)) But thanks anyway!!

Comment: It works as the trigger on cardboard when the app is installed on phone.

Comment: Fire 1 is up button on buetooth remote for google cardboard. But how to use lower button on remote, Fire 2 isn't work?

Comment: @Zarko Ristic I don't know but that is a separate question from what this question was asking. If you want more information form a new question by asking about all the inputs for a specific Bluetooth controller. Note: specifics. The community needs to know specifics about your situation to help you effectively.

Comment: Also if my answer resolved your question for the trigger mark it as correct or submit your own answer to the question on how you got the trigger working and then mark your own answer as correct

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GvrPointerInputModule.Pointer.TriggerDown`