# VR Cardboard SDK 1.120 and Unity 2017.3 : How to detect magnet trigger?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, google-vr

just a problem with old Google cardboard device with magnetic trigger.

I want to make a game with Unity 2017.3 and Google Cardboard SDK 1.120 with the magnetic trigger of the device. But unfortunately, this version of SDK is not supporting the magnetic trigger anymore. I also tried the old version SDK 0.85 for that magnetic trigger support but it was errors when built the APK.

Could you guys give me advice of any C# script or something to take the magnet trigger back to the Google cardboard SDK 1.120 ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: If it has been removed, I don't think it's coming back. Write your own plugin that detects magnetic force. You can do this with the `SensorManager` and `SENSOR_MAGNETIC_FIELD` API for Android. There should be similar API on iOS too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44920645/how-to-access-the-cardboard-trigger-on-google-gvr-in-code-1-6-version-sdk